# Shoud I restore GC if multiple PaintListener-s in SWT?

Tags: java, swt, paint

I can set color, alpha and so on on `GC` in `SWT` when executing `paintControl`.

Should I restore parameters somehow if I have multiple paint listeners?

Comment: you should restore only what  you changed in paint listener.

Answer (score 0):

A new `GC` is created for each paint event on each `Control` so it is not necessary to restore things.

If you have multiple paint listeners **on a single control** then they all receive the same `Event` with the same `GC` for each paint event so you should restore things you change.

Comment: But if I have multiple listener in list, does this mean that each listener receive it's own new event? On my side, if I send event `notifyListeners(SWT.Selection, new Event());` I create only one instance, which travels to each listener?

Comment: Is that multiple listeners (of the same type) on a single control?

Comment: Yes, this is the question